# Get IP address of domain or make DNS request using WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, browser, dns, cross-browser, webassembly

Is it possible to use WebAssembly to make DNS requests or get the IP address of a domain name? If not in a website, what about through a browser plugin?

I've seen that JavaScript doesn't allow making DNS requests or even grabbing the current IP of the domain you've connected even though the browser itself has that data.

I've also seen you can make DNS requests in Node.js so I wonder, because WebAssembly has a different feature-set from in-browser JS, does it also have some server-side capabilities that would allow for either making DNS requests or listening in on the browsers' DNS responses?

Answer (score 1):

No.
There is no API exclusively for WebAssembly. [The MVP spec](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/MVP.md) has even no stable application API nor built-in libraries for WebAssembly (they are working on adding some as post-MVP features). WebAssembly binaries itself can only do pure computations for now.

Currently it is safe to assume that all system functions are implemented through emulating using Javascript. Specifically, they are done by [importing JS code in to WebAssembly modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Using_the_JavaScript_API#Preparing_the_example). So what the JS engine cannot is what WebAssembly cannot.

Security is their main concerns. The WebAssembly team [adding more system features](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/masster/FutureFeatures.md) but they mainly focus on computation features such as threading and SIMD rather than exclusive system features that might break the sandbox. So I don't expect they are going to add low-level access, such as manipulating DNS requests and exposing real filesystem on browsers.